# Fatal error: Failed to create the main isolate (code 8) when using curl with docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi5

I have a Raspberry Pi 5 with Debian 2 installed.
I use there the `signal-cli` API. This was working fine until I had to change to a newer version.

I stopped and deleted my docker image for `signal-cli` and get to the newest version with `docker pull bbernhard/signal-cli-rest-api`.
Afterwards I created a new image with the same name.
I checked with `docker inspect "image"` and saw the version 0.81 was used.
When I now want to use the

```bash
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/receive/<number>'
```

The response is `{"error":"Fatal error: Failed to create the main Isolate. (code 8)\n"}`
Docker version 25.0.4

What can I do or what have I've done wrong (Sorry for asking I'm a docker/linux newbie)

I didn't find anything, hopefully can somebody help me.
What else do you need (logs...?)

Thanks for your help

I would expect, that with updating the `signal-api` and restart the container it will work as good as bevor.

I'm a docker newbie, so right now I'm not sure what i can try to fix it.